# Exporting Users in groups - Powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, security

I am using this script to export groups and users in a SP group.  I am having trouble exporting to csv, how can I do it?

```
$siteUrl = "SiteCollection"
$web = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl


 $site = Get-SPSite $URL

 if (Get-SPWeb($url).HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $true)
 {
    $Web=Get-SPWeb($url)
 }
 else
 {
    $web= $site.RootWeb
 }

 #Get all Groups and Iterate through   
 foreach ($group in $Web.sitegroups)
 {
    write-host " Group Name: "$group.name "`n---------------------------`n"
        #Iterate through Each User in the group
               foreach ($user in $group.users)
                {
                    write-host $user.name  "`t" $user.LoginName  "`t"  $user.Email  | FT
                }
 write-host "=================================="  #Group Separator
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

- Define a variable as `$output = @()`
- and add

> ```
> foreach ($user in $group.users)
>                 {
>                    $output += $user.name  "`t" $user.LoginName  "`t"  $user.Email  | FT
>                 }
> ```

- Then export

> ```
> $Output| export-csv -Path c:\folder\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
> ```

Alternative to use `Out-file` to can append new data

Surround `foreach` with `$()` `| Out-file c:\root\export1.txt -Append`

```
$(foreach ($group in $Web.sitegroups)
 {
    write-host " Group Name: "$group.name "`n---------------------------`n"
        #Iterate through Each User in the group
               foreach ($user in $group.users)
                {
                 $group.name 
                }
 })| Out-file c:\root\export1.txt -Append
```

Comment: Bit of a PS novice here. Where do I put/format in my script :Define a variable as $output = @()